# Spring Boot does not honor spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

when i run spring boot jar from my application on Linux server, always drop schema and remove all data and create the tables again my database type MySQL although i have configure spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none in application.properties none.

Comment: maybe you have another application.properties for a different environment, which clashes with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto?